# SpriteAnimationTicker class

Tags: flutter, flame

What does the SpriteAnimationTicker class does and what are some applications for it?

I am making a game where a character is running with each tap. Each tap will alternate the left and right stride for the character's running.

I achieved this by using 2 sprite sheets as in running_left and running_right. With each tap, I removed the previous sprite and reset its frame to 0 with reset(). But after I upgraded flame, reset() can no longer be used and I cannot find a way to achieve the same thing now.

I suspect SpriteAnimationTicker class might do what I want to do but I don't know what it does or how to apply it.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed correct, the `SpriteAnimationTicker` is used so that the state of the animation isn't stored in the `SpriteAnimation` object, so that that object can be re-used over multiple classes.

The reset method has as such been moved into the ticker:

```dart
yourSpriteAnimationComponent.animationTicker.reset();
```

For this use-case I would recommend either using `flipHorizontally()` (or `flipHorizontallyAroundCenter() if your anchor is not` center'), or use a `SpriteAnimationGroupComponent` where you define the left and right states (you might need more states later too, like jumping etc).